# Element is not clickable in Firefox

Tags: html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have problem with this kind of error:

Element is not clickable at point (791, 394). Other element would receive the click: 
Command duration or timeout: 66 milliseconds

Anyone knows what is about? I am using selenium web driver 2.52 and firefox version 43.5

This is part of the code:

```
private static void waitForLoadingSpinner() throws Exception {
    log("wait for loading spinner");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='loadingGlassPane']")));           
    element.click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='loadingGlassPane']")));
```

After checking cities for example my apply button is not working.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems one of the classic automation errors, another element is overlapping the element you want to click at that moment.You need to wait for the element to be visible in this case.

Comment: Can you share the website? Either element not visible or multiple element are getting located.

Comment: Is there any loading bar exist when you're going to click on desire element??

Comment: @Lauda: How much I need to wait? Is there anything to add on above code to avoid this situation?

Comment: Add a breakpoint or something and see what happens, maybe you need to wait few seconds, maybe you need to to something else like a scroll to top or focus on another element. Sometimes wait does not solve the issue.If you have a loader that is triggered by some actions you need to wait for the loader to disappear or use a wait for the element to be visible with a time (time of the loader is displayed + 1) seconds.

Comment: @Kishan@Saurabh: I have added my filter picture

Comment: Don't supply pictures of the code or you will receive pictures of the fix! You are required to supply code and markup, not pictures of it.

Comment: @Rob: I don't see the point of writing html part from inspect element? But if that is requirement then good to know :).

Comment: You are asking why the element is not clickable. The only way to find this out is to view the HTML and CSS. If one wants to help by creating their own test page, a picture forces them to hand type your example.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code.

```
WebDriverWait wait =new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By locator)).click();
```

Comment: I have tried inside my code, but nothing is happening. I don't know what this error means.

Comment: @marija, it seems you are trying to wait for loading spinner to disappear.  If it is the case, then you don't need to click on it. It seems, the loading spinner disappears before the click action and so the error says "other element will receive the click"

Comment: I have increase thread .sleep on 2000 and also removed click(), but still get same error :(

Comment: wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='loadingGlassPane']")));

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience: When running automation in Firefox, if you want to click on a dojo button (seems what you are using), you can do it in 2 ways:

1) You should find the 'clickable' node - look at the picture below
[image]

2) Use your original button, but call: `actions.moveToElement(yourButton).click()`

Comment: I have tried second solution, but it is crashing... Do you know maybe how can I modify this line wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='loadingGlassPane']"))); beacuse I think this is problem. I would like to modify this if not find element to click on any other spot on browser? My code has been working, but after some update of the servere this element problem pops up

Comment: You said that it's crashing. Can you show which error it threw?
By the way, did you try the same steps manually on Firefox?

Comment: I have done like this      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='loadingGlassPane']"));
          Actions action = new Actions(driver);
         action.moveToElement(element).click().perform(); but still this filter is somehow hidden...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem adding this part:

```
     JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
     js.executeScript("scroll(250, 0)");
     js.executeScript("scroll(0, 250)");
```

Hope this will help someone :)

Regards